# Flutter SingleChildScrollView not scrolling

Tags: flutter

My singleChildScollView won't scroll vertically. I've checked similar questions regarding this problem but none of them sem to work for me.
The page fills up with the items, and the homepage button is placed at the bottom...

[image]

...so it looks correct, it just doesn't let me scroll.
Can anyone help?  [ EDIT - please note in the example code below I have simplified the original widget tree and removed the homepage button]...

```
Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
               child: ListView.builder(
                           scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                           shrinkWrap: true,
                           itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                                  ...list of items here...
                           }
                      ),
          ),
)
```

Comment: you are putting list view inside a SingleChildScrollView which may be the cause of your problem , try to remove the SingleChildScrollView parent widget

Comment: @FatihaIMOUSSAINE, thanks I tried that but then I get the "bottom overflowed by..." message and the yellow/black lines

Comment: I have simplified it a little, so I will update the widget tree above now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@james please check it

```
Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 30,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
                  child: Text("index $index"),
                );
              }
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {Navigator.pop(context);},
            child: Text('Homepage'),
          ),
        ),

      ],
    ),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks - I have tried that and it allows me to scroll. The homepage button is stacked on top (as expected with stack :) ). I will see if I can modify my original code to include this layout and get back to you.

Comment: Ah it was the umissing "physics: ScrollPhysics()" line that I needed !! I feel like a rookie!
Thanks for the help.

Comment: i agree the key point here is to use physics: ScrollPhysics(), with         SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 3):

There is two steps you can do to use `SingleChildScrollView` in a `Column` widget

1. Wrap it in a `SizedBox`
2. Set a `height` to the `SizedBox` widget

Try this out :

```dart
Scaffold(
  body:
    child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                 SizedBox(
                     //set a height
                     height : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/5,
                     child: SingleChildScrollView(
                               child: Column(
                                         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                         children: [
                                             ListView.builder(
                                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                                                  ...list of items here...
                                                }
                                             ),
                                         ],
                               ),
                     ),
                 ),
                 Center(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {Navigator.pop(context);},
                                child: Text('Homepage'),
                        ),
                ),

              ],
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks - I added the SizedBox (swapping out the Expanded widget) but it still doesn't scroll

Comment: I have simplified the widget tree now in the example above...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help, expecially @Jahidul Islam.
I was missing the physics: ScrollPhysics() line!

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `SingleChildScrollView` to work, its parent's height should be defined.
You can achieve this by wrapping the `SingleChildScrollView` in a `Container/SizedBox`, or by wrapping it with the `Expanded` widget.